# How do I modify machine.config via an .msi package

Tags: installation, windows-installer, machine.config

I'm trying to create an installer that will deploy a .NET Managed data provider. In order for the data provider to appear as a provider in application drop-downs, I have to add the provider in the machine.config's  section:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="My Data Provider" 
           invariant="Sample.MyDataProvider" 
           description="My Data Provider" 
           type="Eli.Sample.MyDataProvider, Sample.MyDataProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5b9d34470b87a97f" 
      />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

How do I do this? Just a pointer would be fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest the `XmlConfig` elements for a slightly neater solution. This is what worked for me with WiX toolset v3.11 for .NET Framework 4:

```
<util:XmlConfig Id="AddElement32" File="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]Config\Machine.Config"
                ElementPath="//configuration/system.data/DbProviderFactories"
                Action="create" On="install" Node="element"
                Name="add">
    <util:XmlConfig Id="NameAttribute32" File="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]Config\Machine.Config" ElementId="AddElement32"
                    Name="name"
                    Value="My Data Provider"
                    />
    <util:XmlConfig Id="InvariantAttribute32" File="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]Config\Machine.Config" ElementId="AddElement32"
                    Name="invariant"
                    Value="Sample.MyDataProvider"
                    />
    <util:XmlConfig Id="DescriptionAttribute32" File="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]Config\Machine.Config" ElementId="AddElement32"
                    Name="description"
                    Value="My Data Provider"
                    />
    <util:XmlConfig Id="TypeAttribute32" File="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]Config\Machine.Config" ElementId="AddElement32"
                    Name="type"
                    Value="Eli.Sample.MyDataProvider, Sample.MyDataProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5b9d34470b87a97f"
                    />
</util:XmlConfig>

<util:XmlConfig Id="AddElement32Uninstall" File="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]Config\Machine.Config"
                Action="delete" On="uninstall" Node="element"
                ElementPath="//configuration/system.data/DbProviderFactories"
                VerifyPath="//configuration/system.data/DbProviderFactories/add[\[]@invariant='Sample.MyDataProvider'[\]]"
                />
```

Note that although you can now leave out some of the attributes because you're nesting the elements, you still need the `File` and `ElementId` attributes.

The uninstall `XmlConfig` element seems to need the `VerifyPath` attribute too, so that it can select the correct element to remove.

Answer (score 7):

If your using Wix you can use the [XmlConfig](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_xmlconfig.htm) element.

```
<util:XmlConfig 
        Id="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
        File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
        Action="create" 
        On="install"
        ElementPath="//configuration/system.data/DbProviderFactories" 
        Name="add"
        Node="element" 
        Sequence="1"> 
 </util:XmlConfig> 
 <util:XmlConfig 
        Id="Machine_Config_Xml_2"
        File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
        ElementPath="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
        Name="name"
        Value="My Data Provider" 
        Sequence="2"> 
 </util:XmlConfig>
 <util:XmlConfig 
        Id="Machine_Config_Xml_2"
        File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
        ElementPath="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
        Name="invariant"
        Value="Sample.MyDataProvider" 
        Sequence="2"> 
 </util:XmlConfig>
 <util:XmlConfig 
        Id="Machine_Config_Xml_2"
        File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
        ElementPath="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
        Name="description"
        Value="My Data Provider" 
        Sequence="2"> 
 </util:XmlConfig>
 <util:XmlConfig 
        Id="Machine_Config_Xml_2"
        File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
        ElementPath="Machine_Config_Xml_Root"
        Name="type"
        Value="Eli.Sample.MyDataProvider, Sample.MyDataProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5b9d34470b87a97f" 
        Sequence="2"> 
 </util:XmlConfig>

 <util:XmlConfig 
    Id="Machine_Config_Xml_Uninstall_1"
    File="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.Config"
    Action="delete"
    On="uninstall"
    ElementPath="//configuration/system.data/DbProviderFactories/add[\[]@invariant='Sample.MyDataProvider'[\]]"
    Sequence="1">
 </util:XmlConfig>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a [custom installer action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(VS.80).aspx) and add it to your MSI to do this (I'm assuming you're using a Visual Studio setup project to do this).